# How to emulate location while app isn't running

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ios-simulator

I'm building an iOS 8 app that features GeoFencing. I need to test this and I know that I can emulate the location in Xcode using the preconfigured locations or providing a GPX file. However, as this app needs to act based on region monitoring when it's killed (swiped up in multitasking by user), how can I test it without getting in my car and driving around?

Thanks!