# didEnterRegion fire when app is terminated?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6, cllocationmanager

I've implemented the use of GeoFences in my app. I've created a new CLLocationManager property and initialised it in my app's viewDidLoad method simply like so:

```
[[self.locationManager alloc] init];
```

I set the delegate to self, start monitoring for regions using startMonitoringForRegion:

Then, I emulate my location while running it using Xcode and the methods didEnterRegion and didExitRegion. The app works perfect while running, but I haven't got the chance to test it as I don't know how to emulate my location while the app is terminated, see [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028675/how-to-emulate-location-while-app-isnt-running)

Therefore, I was hoping to get some answers on these questions:

- Can I manage background work just like normal with the didEnterRegion and didExitRegion methods? Like calculating, etc?
- If my app is terminated, I enter a region, open my app - are my variables from didEnterRegion initialised and set up then?
- Do I need to do anything else to set it up to work when my app is terminated, except for the normal CLLocationManager setup that I've done so far?

Thanks!